# Multiple boolean operators

Tags: python, python-3.x

could someone please explain to me why this code returns True? I totally don't understand this one, for my understanding, it should return False.

```
z = 2
y = 1
x = y < z or z > y and y > z or z < y
print(x)
```

Comment: when you're not sure, use parentheses

Comment: also this example makes little sense in real life as `y < z or z > y` boils down to `y < z`

Comment: Why do you think *it should return False*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and` binds more (based on [operator precendence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)) than `or` does. Hence, your boolean expression could also be represented like this:

```
z = 2
y = 1
x = y < z or (z > y and y > z) or z < y
print(x)
```

Clearly, `y < z` is `True` and because only one of the three needs to be `True`, the whole expression evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

`or` has a lower [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `and`, so `y < z or z > y and y > z or z < y` is equivalent to `(y < z) or (z > y and y > z) or (z < y)`, and since `y < z` is `True`, the entire expression is therefore `True` after the evaluation of the `or` operations.